# Can't write to a file when running my code optimized

Tags: c

I have a program that writes data to a binary file, it works when I run it in Visual Studio 2013 in `Debug` mode (no optimization), but when I run it in `Release` mode, with `Maximize Speed` enabled, it doesn't work (the file becomes empty)...

Can you tell me why it might not work?

EDIT:
Dr. Memory log of running the application in `Release` mode, if you see something alarming, please tell me: http://pastebin.com/5s4Z51ZV

Which errors might cause the problem?
Also, should I work on fixing every single one of the errors? or are some of them "false positives"?

EDIT:

After debugging the optimized code via this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/606cbtzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx , I found something very weird was happening when I generate a huffman tree (from a priority queue of characters), this is my code:

```
HNode * generateHuffmanTree(Queue * queue) // generates a huffman tree from a queue of a file's characters.
{
    HNode * root = (HNode *) calloc(1, sizeof(HNode));
    root->left = dequeue(queue); // gets the two smallest-amount characters
    root->right = dequeue(queue); // and puts them into left and right of the root.
    root->character = '\0';
    root->value = root->left->value + root->right->value;
    if (isQueueEmpty(queue)) return root; // end condition, if it's the only thing left.
    enqueue(queue, root); // puts the root back in the queue so it can be a part of the process in the next iteration
#ifdef debug
    printQueue(queue);
#endif
    generateHuffmanTree(queue); // runs the operation again, now with the new root in the queue.
}
```

I can see in the debugger that the problem is not in `queue` as it comes in as it should, but it seems to ignore my declaration of `root`, then when I try to do `root->left` it overwrites the data in `queue`. Anyone know why this might happen and how to find a work around or fix it? Or is it even not the problem?

Comment: Show relevant snippet of your code.

Comment: You are likely invoking undefined behavior of some sort. We can't tell without the relevant code.

Comment: It's a big program... What is considered relevant? Where I `fwrite`? If so, why does it work in Debug mode and not in Release mode?

Comment: The two most likely cases are 1) You are corrupting the memory somewhere with is leading to seemingly unrelated bugs, or 2) You're invoking undefined behavior and the compiler thinks it can optimize out valid code. Try running your program under Dr. Memory, and see if there are any exceptional writes.

Comment: @Kaslai I added to my question the Dr. Memory log, if you can take a look, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hm. The unaddressable accesses, while not desireable, don't really put you at risk for stack smashing or other memory corruption. However they can lead to segfaults, so I would suggest fixing them anyways. It's probably not relevant to the question though. I would say that it's for sure undefined behavior which is causing this.

Comment: @Kaslai So about the undefined behavior, is there a list of all the examples of undefined behavior in C so I can look for that in my code? I found Wikipedia's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior , But is that it?

Comment: @Kaslai: Unaddressable accesses _are_ UB and this may be related to the problem here.

Comment: @shoham: Narrow down the code to something showing similar behavior (might be some work when tracking undefined behavior), try removing everything which doesn't involve array subscript/pointer dereference/memory allocation. And yes, the linked Wikipedia article is about what's meant here. However, there is no complete list of UB, only a list of defined behavior (the C standard) and everything not defined there is undefined (plus the things defined to be undefined). But accessing arrays out of bounds or unallocated memory may be the issue here.

Comment: @mafso I guess so. I'm not too used to the VC++ optimizer, but I've never had issues with the GCC optimizer as far as unaddressable accesses. Unaddressable accesses and leaks are important to get fixed regardless.

Comment: @mafso Thanks, just a question though... Does `Debug` mode solve undefined behavior? Does it fix it? If so, why isn't it standard?

Also, from what I understood, undefined behavior also comes from assumptions the compiler makes while optimizing, like I see here: http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/162289 , this looks similar to something I have in my project, can I turn off this assumption in the compiler and solve my problem (given that this is indeed the problem)?

Comment: It doesn't really fix it; but often, unoptimized code is closer to what ill-formed code _looks_ it would do if it was well-formed.

Comment: No, I don't know if there's a way to turn off only optimizations based on assumptions about overflow. Maybe take a look at the optimization options in your compilers documentation. And if you have a line where you're not sure if it may cause the problem, write a small program with a similar line and see if the behavior differs depending on optimization.

Comment: Show us the part of your code that contains the relevant `fwrite`.

Comment: Put some `printf`s printing relevant information just before calling `fwrite`.

Comment: @mafso I added information about what I think might be the problem, I'll really appreciate if you take a look.

Comment: @Kaslai I added information about what I think might be the problem, I'll really appreciate if you take a look.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems with my `printf`s that `generateHuffmanTree` works fine...

Comment: That's an even stronger hint to undefined behavior; you definitely should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what caused the problem. It had nothing to do with the file specifically, I had a function `initMap` that creates a struct: `Map m`, initializes it with initial values and returns `&map` to another function. I suspected this might be a problem because it will get popped out of the stack and then the pointer will be to nothing. But since it worked while I tested it (in Debug mode) I left it alone. But appearently it doesn't work. So what I did is `Map * map = (Map *) calloc(1, sizeof(Map));` and it worked.

Thanks to mafso and Kalsai for helping me figure it out.